# PowerShell file comparison across multiple servers

Tags: powershell

I'm new to PowerShell so forgive the noob question.  I'm trying to compare a directory across multiple servers to make sure they are in synch.  I'm reading the servers from a `servers.txt` file and setting the first server in the list as the source server.

```
# sets the source server as the FIRST server in the list
$sourceSRV = (Get-Content ./servers.txt -totalcount 1)
$servers = Get-Content ./servers.txt

#Variables for code directories
$code_src01 = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -path "E$\appdirectory"

Foreach ($server in $servers) {
    Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $sourceSRV$code_src01 - 
DifferenceObject $server$code_src01 
}
```

I'm running into the issue on the Compare-Object call, I'm not sure what to pass as the `-ReferenceObject` and `-DifferenceObject` properties.  I want the `ReferenceObject` to be the path of the sourceserver and the file path so `(server1\e$\appdirectory)` and the `-DifferenceObject` to the the other servers in the list `(server2\e$\appdirectory, server3\e$\appdirectory)`

Comment: I would recommend using `windiff` which will let you easily compare two directory trees.

Answer (score 0):

You were very close, but your comparison is wrong:

```
$ServerList = Get-Content -Path .\servers.txt
$Reference = (Get-ChildItem -Path "\\$($ServerList[0])\E$\appdirectory" -Recurse).FullName.Replace("\\$($ServerList[0])",'')

ForEach ($Server in $ServerList)
{
    $CompareArgs = @{
        ReferenceObject = $Reference
        DifferenceObject = (Get-ChildItem -Path "\\$Server\E$\appdirectory" -Recurse).FullName.Replace("\\$Server",'')
    }
    Compare-Object @CompareArgs
}
```

---

To go further, I'd actually utilize `Get-FileHash` on the reference server's file list with the rest of the distribution, but that's outside the scope of my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I do have a question, in your update what is the '-replace '\\\\\w+\\'' doing?  Is it replacing the server/directory path?

Comment: @JBerto Correct.  Otherwise the `.FullName` property includes them in the comparison and everything would be a difference.  I updated it to use `String`'s `.Replace()` method instead of regex.  My answer will purely check whether the same file paths / names exist on the reference server versus the comparison.